# EINSTEIN THEORY OF SPACETIME

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, inertial-frames, equivalence-principle

CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME ANSWERING THIS QUESTION.

HOW WOULD YOU EXPLAIN SPACETIME TO AN UNSCHOOLED PERSON?

I AM STILL A STUDENT AND THINKING AN EXACT EXAMPLE IS QUITE HARD FOR ME.

Comment: This is a good explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNhJY-R3Gwg. You may want to avoid capitalizing every word, [it can come across as shouting](https://www.lifewire.com/why-not-to-write-in-all-caps-1173242).

Comment: I am inclined to vote to reopen as the question seems to ask something that we ought to have a simple explanation for : what do we mean by spacetime in relativity, or at least that's the meaning I read.  There may be a suitable duplicate (with an answer for those without much knowledge of this) but I cannot find it myself.

Comment: I am inclined to vote to keep this question closed. It is not well suited for this forum. It is also annoyingly written in ALL CAPS. WHY? If you are going to ask a bad question at least present it well... Anyways, niels nielsen has already provided an answer that is probably as good an answer as OP is going to get. A book can explain this better than an answer on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend a book by Brian Greene called *The Elegant Universe* which contains a whole section on Einstein's spacetime and how it works. It is written in nontechnical language.